# Match duplicated rows in excel within a range

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-formula, rows, multiple-columns

We have a large excel file with 120000 rows of data where we need to find duplicated records.

The first records is the Master record to match against the list of duplicated records.  We need to confirm whether the duplicate are true and highlight them.

Each record has a number of rows depending on the number of email addresses on file and also physical addresses.

Desired results are:
1.  If the name in the Master record matches the name in the duplicated record, then find a matching any addresses from the master record with any of the addresses in the duplicated records or matching the email addresses from master record with duplicated email addresses in the duplicated records.  Then put a YES in the duplicates column for either matches.

1. Highlight the matching addresses in a colour, highlight the matching names with another colour, highlight the matching email addresses with another colour.

There may be more than one duplicated record found and this is shown in column A

If the names do not match, but everything else matches, we still want to put a NO so that we can do a manual check when going through the excel document.

This is the formula that is being used in column E. It only works if the first address in the master record has a match in the duplicated records. If it is the 2nd address in the Master record that matches, then it doesn't work.

=IF(OR(C2&B2=B2,C2&B2=C2,D2&C2=D2, D2&C2=C2,B2="Addresses",C2="Name"),"",IF(SUM(--(C2&B2&D2=C:C&B:B&D:D))>1,"YES","NO"))

Can you help with fixing the formula and also assisting with highlighting the duplicates?

```
A            B                    C                       D                    E                            
Master   Addresses            Name                   Email address        Duplicate
255812   1 test rd Sydney     John Doe               john.doe@gmail.com   YES
         1 test rd Sydney                            john.doe@gmail.com 
         PO BOX 2 Sydney            

         Addresses            Name                   Email address  
421504   1 test rd Sydney     John Doe               john.doe@gmail.com   YES
Duplicate
records
found: 1                

Master  Addresses             Name                    Email address 
455444  1111 House rd Sydney  Steven Jacks            sjacks@gmail.com     NO
        134 Smart St Sydney         

        Addresses             Name                    Email address 
53421   134 Smart St Sydney   Steven Jacks            sjacks@gmail.com     NO
        1111 House rd Sydney                          stephenj@hotmail.com  
        Level 5, Kings St Syd                       
        134 Smart St Sydney         

        Addresses              Name                   Email address 
13232   Level 5, Kings St Syd  Steven R Jacks         stephenj@hotmail.com  NO

Duplicate
records 
found: 2
```

Comment: Please show an example of the data you're working with.  Or spell out what the columns are, and how the multiple addresses / e-mail addresses are expressed.  What you have written at the bottom looks like a report.  It's a bit hard to visualize what you're working with from your description.

Comment: I couldn't paste the excel table or document.  I have uploaded the file to the location below.  Hope that helps.

http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gd8da5224aa7dcd159994074767577c0fcb9ace793

Comment: Try copying a few rows directly from Excel (highlight them and press CTRL-C) and paste them into here directly (CTRL-V).  I just tried it and it does a pretty good job.  Be sure to include column headers.

Comment: Besides, the fileconvoy site appears to have an issue with its security certificate.  Not something I'm anxious to play with; I doubt others are, either.

Comment: I didn't have an error with the ssl cert.  Try this link below for the same document.  http://wikisend.com/download/689808/duplicates_1112test.xlsx

Comment: Given the complexity of your file layout and the complexity of your conditions I would suggest that anything but a VBA program would fail sooner or later. If you absolutely have to avoid VBA I'd recommend to bring your file in a somewhat more database like shape before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on my comment to your question, here's a way to kind of "normalize your file a bit before proceeding with finding duplicates:

Save the original sort order of the file (Column F - no formula)

Assuming that no Master has more than 999 attached addresses, calculate a key for all real data records and save as value

G2 and down: `=IF(ISNUMBER(A2);A2;IF(AND(A2="";AND(B2<>"";B2<>"Addresses");ISNUMBER(G1));G1+0,001;""))`

H2 and down: `=G2`, then copy/paste as value

[image]

now sort according to your duplication criteria (by name, address)

then add a dup finder formula like "if this row key = prev row key then this counter = prev counter + 1 else this counter = 1", e.g.

I2 and down: `=IF(ISNUMBER(H2);IF(AND(C2<>"";C2=C1;B2=B1);I1+1;1);"")`

[image]

now you can

- filter column I for all values > 1 to identify duplicates. you'll find only John Doe at 1 test rd Sydney ...
- feed back the result via VLOOKUP on the KeyValue column to your original table
- etc ...

  and we're not taking into account different spellings like abbreviations & capitals, add'l white spaces or interpunctations (Rd vs Rd. vs road, Road, 1 vs 1. vs 1.,) - middle initials in names, etc. etc., all of which are the *real pain* for cleaning address files

you can repeat the above for a different sort order (e.g. address + name)

Remember before any sorting you should convert formulas into values!

now ... this all may sound rather complicated ... therefore ... if this is not a one-off but a recurring exercise, I'd think about VBA ...

Comment: Hi Mike, What you did above has given me some good ideas but doesn't fix the problem I'm stuck with.  What I need to do is fix the column E formula so that it looks at the Master record (ie 455444), check that the Person's name matches the duplicate record(s) (53421 and 132232) Person's name. If it matches, then it compares the relevant master record addresses (B10,B11) against its duplicates (B13,B14,B15,B16), then it puts a YES in the column or if the same duplicate is found for the email address match. The other part would be to make it highlight the fields for where a duplicate is found.

Comment: The result of E10 should be a YES if my formula was correct as 134 smart st is a match address on both master record (455444) and the first of 2 duplicated records (53421).  There is also a match in the email addresses (D10, D13) so either of the name and address match  or name and email address match would have resulted in YES in the duplicates field. These reference points are based on the first screen shot you posted.